# Drawable setAlpha not working on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, drawable, alpha

I'm using following function to enable and disable drawables...

```
public static void setDrawableState(Drawable d, boolean enabled)
{
    if (d == null)
        return;
    d.mutate(); // so drawables don't share state anymore
    if (enabled)
        d.setAlpha(255);
    else
        d.setAlpha(100);
}
```

This worked on all phones I've tried yet, now I see it does not seem to work on android 4.4.2 (maybe it's not even version specific).

Is there another (better) way to set the alpha of a drawable? Or am I'm missing something?

Comment: Has it worked on older versions?

Comment: yes, perfectly... on `ImageButtons`, `MenuItems`, `ActionItems`... as long as I applied it to the drawable, it worked... Can't tell if it worked on all devices, but it did on mine (HTC One Mini, 4.4.3 and 4.3)

Comment: I don't think your using mutate right. It returns the mutable instance.

Comment: could you explain, how you would solve the problem? Actually, I just googled a little bit and even found a blog on which my technique is explained... http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

Comment: I don't know. I've never needed to do this. I'd just setAlpha on the view or setEnabled(false)

Comment: where Drawable d comes from?

Comment: From a `ImageButton`, `MenuItem`or `ActionItem`... Or sometimes even a drawable from the resources directly, which is only used aftercalling above function... Non of them work anymore... But did on other versions...

Answer (score 3):

Because drawables might share the same state, changing the drawable state will not have any effect. You need to mutate the drawable, for example in your code, try something like:

```
d.mutate().setAlpha(100);
```

[Android developer Blogs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) has a great blog post explaining more on drawable state and mutations.

Comment: actually, that's exactly what I do and what works on some android versions, but not on all... In my code, I even commented the line where I call `mutate` and explain, that I do that for exact the same reason you mention...

Answer (score 0):

in case you wanna be really sure:

```html
Drawable d2 = d.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();
d2.setAlpha(100)
```